# How do I read the string xml string in java?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, xml-parsing

I got a response from API like string xml. How do I retrieve data from string xml.
String is something like `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">500226#Mr Santosh Sarangi#TPCODL</string>`

I need only this  `500226#Mr Santosh Sarangi#TPCODL`  data. How do I do that. I follow like this but not able to get the data:--

```java
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource src = new InputSource();
src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(inputLine1));

Document doc = builder.parse(src);

String age = doc.getElementsByTagName("http://tempuri.org/").item(0).getTextContent();
String name = doc.getDocumentElement().toString();;
```

Comment: The tag is named `"string"`, not `"http://tempuri.org/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML contains a namespace so it is better to enable namespace awareness.
If all your XMLs are so simple you can simply get the text content out of the root element. The root element is the document's first child:

```
try {
  final String xmlString = "<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">500226#Mr Santosh Sarangi#TPCODL</string>";
  System.out.println(xmlString);
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
  InputSource source = new InputSource(reader);
  Document document = builder.parse(source);
  System.out.println(document.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">500226#Mr Santosh Sarangi#TPCODL</string>
500226#Mr Santosh Sarangi#TPCODL
```